# The Gradient / Derivative of Least Squares of 2D Image Convolution

Tags: image-processing, convolution, deconvolution, linear-algebra, gradient

Given the objective function:

$$ \frac{1}{2} {\left\| h \ast x - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} $$

Where $ h $ is the 2D convolution kernel and $ x $ is the 2D convolution image and $ y $ is a given 2D image.

What would be:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| h \ast x - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} }{\mathrm{d} h}, \; \frac{\mathrm{d} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| h \ast x - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} }{\mathrm{d} x} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach would be writing each case using Matrix Form of the convolution.
In this answer we assume the discrete convolution is applied only on valid support (Matching MATLAB's `valid` parameter for the convolution).
Namely, given $ x \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} $ and $ h \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times l} $ then $ h \ast x \in \mathbb{R}^{ \left( m - k + 1 \right) \times \left( n - l + 1 \right) } $. Needless to say $ m \geq k $ and $ n \geq l $ as otherwise the operation isn't well defined. Pay attention that this form of convolution isn't commutative.

**Remark**
For full convolution the problem is easier as the operation is commutative hence no difference between the gradient with respect to $ h $ or $ x $ as one could switch them.

#### Gradient with Respect to Convolution Kernel $ h $

The matrix form is given by:

$$ f \left( h \right) = \frac{1}{2} {\left\| X h - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} $$

Where $ X $ is the 2D Convolution Matrix Form of the image. Then:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d} f \left( h \right) }{\mathrm{d} h} = {X}^{T} \left( X h - y \right) $$

The $ {X}^{T} $ forms a correlation (Versus Convolution) with full support of the operation (Equivalent of the `full` convolution shape in MATLAB syntax).

Hence we have:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| h \ast x - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} }{\mathrm{d} h} = x \star \left( h \ast x - y \right) $$

In MATLAB Code:

```
conv2(mX(end:-1:1, end:-1:1), (conv2(mX, mH, CONVOLUTION_MODE_VALID) - mY), CONVOLUTION_MODE_VALID);
```

#### Gradient with Respect to Convolution Image $ x $

The matrix form is given by:

$$ f \left( x \right) = \frac{1}{2} {\left\| H x - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} $$

Where $ H $ is the 2D Convolution Matrix Form of the kernel. Then:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d} f \left( x \right) }{\mathrm{d} x} = {H}^{T} \left( H x - y \right) $$

In MATLAB Code:

```
conv2((conv2(mX, mH, CONVOLUTION_MODE_VALID) - mY), mH(end:-1:1, end:-1:1), CONVOLUTION_MODE_FULL);
```

#### MATLAB Code

The full code is available on my [StackExchange Signal Processing Q59089 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `SignalProcessing\Q59089` folder)..

Comment: I really with MathWorks added option to select *Correlation* or *Convolution* mode in its `conv` function.

Answer (score 1):

My (lazy) option is to dig into the [Matrix cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/publication_details.php?id=3274) ([pdf](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf)), by Kaare Brandt Petersen and Michael Syskind Pedersen, namely section 2.4 Derivatives of Matrices, Vectors and Scalar Forms. They have a whole section on complex matrices as well.

Comment: Why dig if you have the answer above :-)? The tricky part is the `valid` use. See my answer.

Comment: Why ask if you already had an answer :-)? I was pondering on the notion of "the easiest approach"

Comment: The idea of the site, as I see it, is create a knowledge resource. Many times I have seen on different forums people looking for the gradients of those equations. Hence I thought it would be great to have them properly described accompanied by code.

Comment: The great thing will be others adding their own approach to solve it.