# How to produce self-adjoint filters using Gaussian and motion blur in Matlab?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, image-restoration

I am trying to write a Matlab code to produce motion and Gaussian blur. Here is my code:

```
f0=imread('cameraman.png');
[Nx,Ny,Nz]=size(f0);
 if Nz>1;f0=double(rgb2gray(f0));
 else
     f0=double(f0);
 end

blurfilter1 = fspecial('gaussian', [7 7], 1);
blurfilter2 = fspecial('motion',5,30);

Au = @(u) imfilter(u,blurfilter1,'symmetric');

Bu = @(u) imfilter(u,blurfilter2,'symmetric');
```

In above code, operators Au and Bu will produce Gaussian blur and motion blur respectively. However, I need these two operators to be self-adjoint. I have found the following code for producing self-adjoint opearots but I am not sure whether it works for both Gaussian and blur operators. Here is the code:

```
Au = @(u) imfilter(imfilter(u,blurfilter1,'symmetric'),blurfilter1','symmetric');
Bu = @(u) imfilter(imfilter(u,blurfilter2,'symmetric'),blurfilter2','symmetric');
```

I really appriciate it if anyone could please help me to build self-adjoint Au and Bu operators for Gaussian and motion blur.

Comment: crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75445529/how-to-produce-self-adjoint-filters-using-gaussian-and-motion-blur-in-matlab

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks! Reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Gaussian

To start, `fspecial('gaussian'` is deprecated; the `fspecial` documentation explains how to do the same thing, but better.

Why do you use an n-dimensional convolution (`imfilter`) if you're actually after 2 sequences of 1-dimensional convolutions?

Something like (excuse me, this is untested, I uninstalled my Matlab recently)

```
x = [-3:3]
sigma = 1
gaussian = exp(- x.^ 2 / (2 * sigma ^ 2));
self_adjoint_filter = @(img, impresp1d) conv2(impresp1d, impresp1d, img)
Au = @(img) self_adjoint_filter(img, gaussian)
```

should do the trick.

## Motion blur

That's not a self-adjunct operation. It has a definite direction, so eigenvalues can't be the same magnitude.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and valuable answer. Yes, now I understand that motion blur is not a self-adjoint operator and I am working on  the structure of its adjoint. Many thanks.

Comment: @Marcus, Hi Marcus, maybe i'm wrong, but what if the motion blur kernel were symmetric around the origin ?

Comment: then it wouldn't be a motion blur.

Comment: as an example,  what is wrong with a line centered around origin to be a motion blur kernel?

Comment: How's convolution with that a self-adjoint operator? The moment you transpose that, you get a complete different result.

Comment: the "convolution kernel" is not the "convolution operator", and it's the convolution operator should be self adjoint not the kernel itself.  I explained in my answer below

Comment: @MohammadM exactly! The operation "convolve with a specific kernel" is a linear mapping (==linear operator)  and it *can* be self-adjoint, but that only works, exactly as you say, if its Eigenvalues are real (otherwise, the conjugate of the Eigenvalues can't be the same as the Eigenvalues). Now, take a step back: self-adjoint means: the adjoint of the operator is the same as the operator. That means, for a real-entry operator, that it's diagonally symmetrical. A convolution operator is a band-structure tensor replicating the kernel along its main diagonal,and thus,kernel symmetry is necessary.

Comment: sorry marcus, i lost you at "thus,kernel symmetry is necessary".

Comment: I wrote a code to check it in practice. if the motion blur kernel (or any other kernel) were centered around origin, it will produce a self-adjoint operator. the matlab convmtx2 return the paddded output (the operator is not square), so i cant check the symmetry of the operator itself, but i used some random input to check it.

Comment: kern = fspecial('motion',6,45);
kern_size = size(kern);
conv_op = convmtx2(kern,im_size);


pad_size = (kern_size-1)/2;
im_size = [100 100];
im_padded_size = im_size+kern_size-1;

im = rand(im_size);
im_padded = padarray(im,pad_size);


Op_im_padded = conv_op*im(:);
adjointOp_im = conv_op.'*im_padded(:);
adjointOp_im_padded = padarray(reshape(adjointOp_im,im_size),pad_size);

sum(Op_im_padded(:)~=Op_im_padded(:))

Comment: @MohammadM I don't have matlab to verify your code, so I'll have to understand it by reading it, which really won't work, I'm afraid, since I don't even understand what is what in there; But: the `conv_op` is what's supposed to be a self-adjoint operator, right. So, as you know how to construct that from the kernel, i.e., what `convmtx2` actually does, you see how the kernel structure effects the self-adjointness of the resultant operator, right?

Comment: @MohammadM also, what does *being a self-adjoint operator* mean, for an operator that operates on images? Right, it means that the effect of the operator is the same, whether you apply it directly, or you apply its adjoint. Now, if take the adjoint of, for example, a horizontal motion blur (the operator, not the kernel), I'd expect that to be a vertical motion blur, unless I'm really missing something here. And since these two blurs don't do the same to every image, the horizontal blur operator can't be self-adjoint.

Comment: the whole code should be 2 line, but the problem is, output of convmtx is not a square operator, it takes non-padded input but return the output as if the input were zero padded. so i have to handle these paddings myself.

Comment: all i'm saying is that, if the kernel has a real valued fourier transform, then the resulting operator is self-adjoint. and to have a real valued fourier transform the kernel must have  even symmetry.

Comment: also about the code, it is comparing the output of operator with the adjoint operator and the outputs are the same using a random input.

Comment: but then you're somehow not doing the adjoing of a non-symmetrical convolution.

Comment: transpose of a horizontal motion kernel is vertical one, but the adjoint of a horizontal motion blur operator is a motion blur where the kernel is inverted around the origin.

Comment: if you consider it in time domain. the adjoint operator is like the anti-causal version of causal filter.

Comment: @MohammadM I'll have to write this down as convolution tensor, but that's a good point.

Comment: @MohammadM, You may read about the adjoint in https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/59089. If you're after a code for the convolution matrix, see https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/54884.

Answer (score 1):

First there are functions convmtx and convmtx2 which returns the matrix operator form of any convolution kernel.

Second, if you consider the convolution operator, the complex sinusoidal are their eigenfunctions and the amplitude of transfer function is their eigenvalues. So, if the operator is selfadjoint, it must have real eigenvalues and in order to have a selfadjoint convolution operator the Fourier transform of kernel must have real values. If a function is real valued in Fourier space then it must have even symmetry in spatial domain.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable answer and your time.